# Anchor test without AVX2 CPU

Tags: solana, solana-cli, anchor-solana

After initialising a project with `anchor init`, when I run `anchor-test`, it gives me this message at the last.

`Unable to get recent blockhash. Test validator does not look started. Check .anchor/test-ledger/test-ledger-log.txt for errors. Consider increasing [test.startup_wait] in Anchor.toml.`

The expected output at last should be the transaction hash but I don't get it.

When I use `solana-test-validator` it returns `Aborted(Core Dumped)`. It seems like my CPU is not AVX2 compatible for which I am not able to run `solana-test-validator`.

The project is instructing me to `build from source`.

What to do now?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you'll need to build `solana-test-validator` from source!  This isn't very hard to do thankfully, and the steps go:

- Install Rust:

```
$ curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
$ source $HOME/.cargo/env
$ rustup component add rustfmt
```

- Install build dependencies, for Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev libudev-dev pkg-config zlib1g-dev llvm clang make
```

- Download the source code:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/solana-labs/solana.git
$ cd solana
```

- Build the test validator:

```
$ cargo build --bin solana-test-validator --release
```

- Run it:

```
$ ./target/release/solana-test-validator
```

More information directly in the repo: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana#building